# How to display Data as html table?

Tags: javascript, php, database, html-table

I am trying to display `tabular` data from my database.
I have the following data to display:

```
title              name                job                      email
manager            Jeff               _____                     _____
developer          Jerry           develop web              jer@test.com    
_____               Harry               IT                      ______
```

The director will enter the blank field in my table in my webpage.

The data is stored in the database as a single text column. As far as best practices go, should I be storing this data in the database as pre-generated HTML or as a delimited string?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason to store any actual HTML code in the database here.  Just store the values as data and display the values in HTML on the front-end.

Comment: The problem is our DB structure is odd and there is only 1 field to store the entire data (title, name, job, email, manager, Jeff...etc)

Comment: In that case the proper course of action is to fix the database structure so that it supports the use cases of the application.  Storing the entire table as one big HTML field in the database is definitely not the answer.

Comment: If changing the database structure isn't possible for whatever reason. It will be better to serialize the data to something like xml/json etc. Sure having a better database structure is the way to go. Serialized data should be used in last resort. Storing html directly should be avoided in your case if the data could be edited for example.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I see, I will probably end up serialize data. Thanks for the tips

Comment: I don't really agree that this question is off topic. The user already demonstrated they have a minimal understanding of the problem being solved - no they didn't include code samples of attempted solutions, but they did understand what they wanted to do. The question could be reworded to further comply with the question checklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, it's always better to keep the data stored just as data, and keep all "view" logic elsewhere. Storing the data as HTML can also cause (a multitude of) problems later such as, if you decide to add a web service.

**Update:**
I read your comment above - even if you only have one column to store your data in, you can `serialize` a data structure and store it there.

see: [php.net serialize() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: so I can serialize the data before I store it to the DB correct? +1

Comment: yes, and then upon retrieval you can `unserialize()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php